# Root-Drive-Agnostic copy

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I want to write a bat file in windows which would do copy some files into the current directory:

```
copy C:\Folder1\Folder2\file1.ext .\
copy C:\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\file2.ext2 .\
...
```

I would like to have the following behavior: If the bat is executed from a path with root drive X, I want it to copy the same files (with the same paths) from X

```
copy X:\Folder1\Folder2\file1.ext .\
copy X:\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\file2.ext2 .\
...
```

How can I achieve this? i.e. how can I get the root drive's name from the current directory?
Hope my question was clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can’t you simply leave out the drive letter? AFAIK it’s optional, `\Folder\Foo` should be a valid absolute path on the current drive.

Comment: I never knew I could! Testing now :)

Comment: Test passed. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

The rule of batch language is that when you don't know how to do something, it probably involves `for`.

```
for /F %%I in ("%CD%") do set CURRENT_DRIVE=%%~dI
```

Comment: `echo %~d0` is a bit shorter, it's the drive letter where the batch is executed

Comment: @Cat: Eschew obfuscation and surplusage. Espouse elucidation

Comment: @jeb: No, it's a driver letter where the batch file is.